# How can I downgrade openssl via apt-get?

Tags: apt, openssl

After a recent upgrade, I am having some SSL connection problems.  I would like to downgrade openssl temporarily to see if the issues go away.

The current version of `openssl` installed is `1.0.1-4ubuntu5.32` and the previous version was `5.31`.  However, when I try:

```
apt-get install openssl=1.0.1-4ubuntu5.31
```

I get:

```
E: Version '1.0.1-4ubuntu5.31' for 'openssl' was not found
```

I thought this was the correct procedure for installation a specific version?

Comment: Which is your Ubuntu release version? (e.g. 14.04)

Comment: I'd suggest you simply don't do it. Download the version you want from OpenSSL's website and compile it (or get a binary from somewhere you trust, I don't think OpenSSL provides binaries).

Comment: Is there a *good reason* why would you dowgrade openssl? [That version](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openssl/1.0.1-4ubuntu5.32) fix [2 moderated and one low non breaking issue](https://www.openssl.org/news/secadv/20151203.txt)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I do not believe that a downgrade will solve your problem. But you asked:

The package `openssl=1.0.1-4ubuntu5.31` isn't longer in the Precise repositories, because the latest version is now `1.0.1-4ubuntu5.32`. But the package is still available in the PPA of the [*“Ubuntu Security Team” team*](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-security/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+build/7531893).

For version `1.0.1-4ubuntu5.31`

```
wget https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-security/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+build/7531893/+files/openssl_1.0.1-4ubuntu5.31_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i openssl_1.0.1-4ubuntu5.31_amd64.deb
```

But I suspect that you have to downgrade other packages listed [here](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-security/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+build/7531893).

The downgrade is temporary. After a

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

or for a better feeling a

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

the latest version will we installed again.

Comment: and this will leave his installation in a complete mess.... just saying.

Comment: @LittleByBlue Pretend you can much. Maybe you should be more specific. Either the package can be installed or not. And after that, a simple `sudo apt-get upgrade` will install the latest versions again.

Comment: I just dried to do a `downgrade`. this let to a new installation.... Btw: `sudo apt-get update` will definitly ___not___ install the newest version. `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` would _maybe_, but as you are `dpkg` forcing to hold the old package, most likely `apt` would leave you with your mess.

Comment: No. `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` installs new major versions. `1.0.1-4ubuntu5.32` isn't a new major version. And there is a `sudo apt-get upgrade` in my comment.

Comment: oops. sorry, but the part with dpkg is still true.

Comment: Again no. `dpkg -i` installs a package without forcing anything and doesn't set a package on hold.

Comment: @A.B. -- thank you for this. You are correct, it did not solve my problem.  But it was the only change to this server since the problem started, so it was worth a try. Fortunately, it went exactly as you said -- a "dpkg -i" downgraded the package, and an "apt-get upgrade" put the new one back.

Comment: @Eric great :) than it's time to accept an answer with a click on the check mark at the left side of the best fitting answer :)

Comment: @A.B. -- thanks, my first post here, and I forgot to click.  Now done.

Answer (score 4):

According to https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openssl, there is no version `1.0.1-4ubuntu5.31` of the package `openssl` in any 12.04 (Precise Pangolin) repository any more.

The only available versions of `openssl` for 12.04 as of today (2015-12-30) are:

- **`1.0.1-4ubuntu5.32`** from the `main` repository's `updates` and `security` channel (2015-12-07)
- **`1.0.1-4ubuntu3`** from the `main` repository's `release` channel (2012-04-19)

The `1.0.1-4ubuntu5.31` version you want to downgrade to was replaced and is no longer available. You can only **downgrade to `1.0.1-4ubuntu3`**, if you don't mind a 3 years old version (which probably contains a few serious bugs and security holes!) or **find a PPA hosting a not that outdated version** of `openssl`.

Answer (score 0):

Apt can only install stuff that is actually in the repositories. Superseeded packages are removed from the respositories. Debian makes older versions of their repositories available in an apt-get compatible form on snapshot.debian.org but I don't know of any direct equivilent for Ubuntu.

Older versions of ubuntu packages are available for download on launchpad. Unfortunately the procedure for finding them is not especially obvious. As far as I can tell you will have to manually download such packages and install them with dpkg -i

If you go to a source package on launchpad (e.g https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openssl ) you can click on "view full publishing history". This will take you to a page with a long list of versions. Find the one you want and it will take you to a page for that version (e.g. https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openssl/1.0.1-4ubuntu5.31 ) on that page you will find links to the builds for different architectures and those pages will have download links for the packages built from the source. You can then download them.

Note: in thie case the links for the builds go to pages referencing the "security team PPA". Afaict this is because security updates are first built in a PPA and then only later migrated to the main ubuntu archive.

P.S. Note that the "openssl" binary package contains tools. The openssl libaries (which are what I think you really care about) are in the "libssl1.0.0" package.

P.P.S If you don't want your next run of apt-get upgrade or similar to upgrade the package again you will need to set up some form of hold or pinning to stop it doing so.

Comment: thank you very much for this.  It was fairly difficult to find the libssl1.0.0_1.0.1-4ubuntu5.31_i386.deb (fwiw, it was at https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-security/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+build/7531896/+files/libssl1.0.0_1.0.1-4ubuntu5.31_i386.deb) but I eventually found it.